# Assign value of another table according to multiple conditions

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have two separate tables, without an existing relationship, similar to the ones below. 
What I am trying to do is to multiply the SalesAmount by the respective Royalty slot, according to the following conditions.

Sales[Store] = Royalties[Store]
Sales[Year] = Royalties[Year]
Sales[Category] = Royalties[Category]

And then slot assignment according to this logic

**SALES** SalesAmount = 160

**ROYALTIES**

- Slot 1 -- from 0 to 100 -- 5%.
- Slot 2 -- from 100 to 200 -- 10%.

Then the value of royalties should be:

- Slot 1 = 100 * 5% = 5
- Slot 2 = 60 * 10% = 6

***Royalties value*** = 5 +6 = 11

Tab. **SALES**

| Store | Year | Category | SalesAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022 | X | 250 |
| B | 2022 | Y | 260 |

Tab. **ROYALTIES**

| INDEX | Store | Year | Category | n_slot | initial_value | final_value | royalties_pct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2022 | X | 1 | 0 | 100 | 5% |
| 2 | A | 2022 | X | 2 | 100 | 200 | 7% |
| 3 | A | 2022 | X | 3 | 200 | 300 | 9% |
| 4 | B | 2022 | Y | 1 | 0 | 80 | 4% |
| 5 | B | 2022 | Y | 2 | 80 | 160 | 6% |
| 6 | B | 2022 | Y | 3 | 160 | 240 | 8% |

How can I fix this to get the correct result?

Answer (score 0):

If you feel like doing it in M / Powerquery

Code for **SALES** query

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="SALESTABLE"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Store", type text}, {"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Category", type text}, {"SalesAmount", Int64.Type}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Royalty", each GetRoyalties([Store],[Year],[Category],[SalesAmount]))
in #"Added Custom"
```

Code for function **GetRoyalties** which pulls from query **ROYALTIES**

```
( xStore as text, xYear as number, xCategory as text, xValue as number) as number => 
let  #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(ROYALTIES, each [Store] = xStore and [Year] = xYear and [Category] = xCategory),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Custom", each if xValue>[final_value] then [royalties_pct]*([final_value]-[initial_value]) else if xValue<[initial_value] then 0 else (xValue-[initial_value])*[royalties_pct]),
Total = List.Sum(#"Added Custom"[Custom])
in Total
```